# How to hide "Deprecated: mysql_connect()" warning?

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem.. Well.. The code that I am using is working like a dream but this message makes page look awful

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
```

I want to hide this message from the page. Is it possible and if so.. How?

It shows that message in this page:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
 header("Location: panel.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 if($row['password']==md5($upass))
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
  header("Location: panel.php");
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('Nimimerkki/Salasana väärin, yritä uudelleen');</script>
        <?php
 }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Kirjaudu Adminpaneeliin</title>
<style>
/*CSS File For Sign-In webpage*/
#body-color{
background-image: url("/admin/kuvat/adminbg.gif");
}
#Sign-In{
border:3px solid #a1a1a1;
padding:9px 35px; 
background:#58FA58;
width:250px;
border-radius:20px;
box-shadow: 7px 7px 6px;
}
#button{
border-radius:10px;
width:100px;
height:40px;
background:#01DF01;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:20px
}
</style>
<!-- Koodi -->
</head>
<body id="body-color">
    <center><img src="/admin/kuvat/adminpaneeli.gif">
<div id="Sign-In">
<fieldset style="width:30%"><legend>Kirjaudu</legend>
<form method="post">
Sähköposti <br><input type="text" name="email" size="40">
<br>
Salasana <br><input type="password" name="pass" size="40">
<br>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="btn-login" value="Kirjaudu!">
</form>
</fieldset>
<br><font color="red"><i>Ongelmia kirjautumisessa?<br>Ota yhteyttä Sulivixiin!</i></font>
</div>
<br><br>
<a href="http://kamakellari.eu"><img src="/admin/kuvat/etusivulle.gif"></a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW, why you are using deprecated function, use mysqli* instead

Comment: _The mysql extension is deprecated_ means: Pleaseeee don't use it because it is deprecated.

Comment: If you don't use, the warning won't show. Also, stop using deprecated HTML tags as well. Your HTML codes look really old.

Comment: Do not use mysql_* functions because it has been removed in php7

Comment: @Thamilan and  B001ᛦ : a reason for running a site that calls deprecated functions is when you need to copy some feature from an archived web site that you still have on localhost.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For your own safety: Just don't use `mysql_connect`!

Switch to [mysqli or pdo](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp).

---

Anyway to hide/suppress deprecated warnings you may do:

`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);`

or to suppress all errors/warnings:

`error_reporting(0);`

Comment: What I should use instead of that?

Comment: Use `PDO` or `mysqli`. @Pvtrixx

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by turn off reporting error type of **E_DEPRECATED**.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Put above line at the top of the PHP script to avoid such messages.

Though

> **mysql_*()** extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the **MySQLi** or **PDO_MySQL** extension
>   should be used.

Make sure you update your scripts **ASAP**.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the option with adding "@" worked only:

```
@mysql_pconnect()
```

Comment: after doing a lot of research on how to remove this warning from joomla, your solution was the only one that worked for me, thank you!

Comment: fast solution and works! I agree that PDO or MySQLi is the ultimate solution but after inheriting several big old projects the conversion is not an easy neither fast assignment and we don't want to get "bombarded" with the same warning every sec